# Applying Styling to Highlighted Text in a Form Input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal form input (in my specific case, a textarea one), and I'm trying to make it so that when a user selects a specific area of text and presses one of the buttons, that highlighted text will then be either bolded, italicized, or underlined. The issue I'm having is that I can properly highlight the text, but when I press one of the buttons, rather than applying the styling to it, it just appends the HTML tag around it that would apply the styling.

For example: if I have the word 'banana' but I wanted to make it look like '**banana**', instead of getting that, I get something like `<strong>banana</strong>`, and I'm unsure as to why. Below is my code.

This is my formatting text function

```js
function formatText(command) {
  var inputField = document.getElementById('alertBody')
  var selectionStart = inputField.selectionStart;
  var selectionEnd = inputField.selectionEnd;
  var selectedText = inputField.value.slice(selectionStart, selectionEnd)

  if (command === 'bold') {
    selectedText = `<strong>${selectedText}</strong>`
  } else if (command === 'italic') {
    selectedText = `<i>${selectedText}</i>`
  } else if (command === 'underline') {
    selectedText = `<u>${selectedText}</u>`
  }

  if (selectedText) {
    var formattedText = document.createElement('span')
    formattedText.innerHTML = selectedText
    inputField.value = inputField.value.slice(0, selectionStart) + formattedText + inputField.value.slice(selectionEnd)
    inputField.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    inputField.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modalDiv mb-3">
  <h5>Alert Details</h5>
  <div>
    <div class="formatting-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="formatText('bold')">B<i class="fa fa-bold"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="formatText('italic')">I<i class="fa fa-italic"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="formatText('underline')">U<i class="fa fa-underline"></i></button>
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="alertBody" rows="3" style="resize: vertical;"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another thing to note as well as that all of this is in google app script as well

Comment: You can't modify a textarea text like that. Your best option is most likely to use contenteditable on an element like a div.

Comment: @imvain2 that was the correct way to go, thank you